# How can I address errors in my iOS project which I hope to submit to app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

When I tried to build an archive for an app I am trying to submit (my first submission), I got a bunch of errors, mostly about import errors related to Darwin:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/PrecompiledHeaders/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix-gxthjnzoqzlexccyjihvntdifuwt/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch.pch Steampunk\ Clock/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Ancient\ Steampunk\ Clock-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Ancient\ Steampunk\ Clock-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Ancient\ Steampunk\ Clock-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Ancient\ Steampunk\ Clock-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Steampunk\ Clock.build/Release-iphoneos/Steampunk\ Clock.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos --serialize-diagnostics /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/PrecompiledHeaders/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix-gxthjnzoqzlexccyjihvntdifuwt/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/PrecompiledHeaders/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix-gxthjnzoqzlexccyjihvntdifuwt/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk\ Clock/Steampunk\ Clock/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch -o /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Steampunk_Clock-cblavmmgjxgqzpfwzbpirbdjpspm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Steampunk\ Clock/PrecompiledHeaders/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix-gxthjnzoqzlexccyjihvntdifuwt/Steampunk\ Clock-Prefix.pch.pch

error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
1 error generated.
/Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:7:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#import 
 ~~~~~~~^
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKitDefines.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#import 
 ~~~~~~~^
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from :1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include 
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: fatal error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include 
 ~~~~~~~~^
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
While building module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/objc/message.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include       // for __DARWIN_NULL
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
While building module 'Security' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:24:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:32:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include 
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
8 errors generated.
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'CoreGraphics' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:8:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:159:11: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
# include 
  ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'CoreImage' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIColor.h:10:
In file included from :1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImage.h:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import 
 ~~~~~~~^
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CoreVideo.h:16:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include 
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'CoreText' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/NSText.h:9:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CoreText.h:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTDefines.h:29:11: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
# include 
  ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMediaTiming.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include/stdint.h:33:16: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
# include_next 
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
error: invalid deployment target '5.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jonathan/Desktop/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock/Steampunk Clock-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
While building module 'OpenGLES' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:
In file included from :1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#include 
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
4 errors generated.
22 errors generated.
25 errors generated.
```

So it looks like I have asked for iOS 5.0 compatibility for a 64-bit device; how do I clear that?

And how else can I address these errors?

Comment: arm64 only runs on iOS7 so you can either remove arm64 from the architectures or set iOS7 as your deployment target

Comment: probably change minimum IOS to 7.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found by a close reading of the error. It appears to indicate that arm64 is not supported for your app which is targeting 5.0.0. If this answer satisfy's your use-case please don't forget to accept the answer so that other users will locate the solution.

**High-level concepts**

Arm64 was just introduced to support iOS7 so it did not exist on iOS5 devices. Something to keep in mind is that iOS5 devices will not support any of the iOS7 specific features.

**Low-level detail**

Specific to the error you are seeing:

**Note the definition of the Valid Architecture settings:**

A space-separated list of architectures for which the target should actually be built. For each target, this list is intersected with the list specified in 'Architectures', and the resulting set is built. This allows individual targets to “opt out” of building for particular architectures. If the resulting set of architectures is empty, no executable will be produced. [VALID_ARCHS]

You can change the architecture of the device you are targeting by removing the arm64 text from your debug/release code. The effect of this is that your app will run in 32 bit mode only on 5s devices. Your current error should disappear when you remove the arm64 setting.

**Select your Project > Click on Build Settings >**
[image: Valid Architectures]

**Search for 'arch' (no quotes) >**
[image: Search Term]

**Double-click into the White Space (Under the Target and Project Column) > Select arm64 > Hit the Minus button on the bottom of the popup box**

[image: Popup Menu]

Answer (score 1):

iOS5 is a 32bit operating system.

If you want to support a deployment target of iOS5 then you need to go to the Build Settings and remove arm64 from the architectures, but leave it in the valid architectures. Just keep armv7 and armv7s. 64 bit devices (at this moment only the iPhone5 S) are capable of running 32 bit code. So unless you have written code to take advantage of the 64bit processor then arm64 is not vital to be included in the architectures.

If you really want to support arm64 or you have no requirement to support any older versions of iOS then you will need to change the deployment target to iOS7

Answer (score 0):

A significant amount of these errors want you to change your Deployment target from 5.0 to 7.0

If you do change it to 7.0, it means that people running iOS7 will be able to download and run your app, but anyone with an older version of iOS will not.

Alternately, if you want to support older versions of iOS, you'll have to find all the parts of your code which are not supported by older versions, and write some supporting code.

Changing the target is easy, it's on the "General" tab of the app's target.